# Help with using RegionPlot3D to plot output of Reduce

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, inequalities

Is there a simple way to take this output from Reduce:

```
((-360. + 11.25 c2 + 14.5 c3 < c4 < 
  5.1917 c2 + 4.4417 c3 && 
 0.602319 c2 + c3 < 
  35.7913 && ((c3 > 0 && c2 < 59.4226 && 
     c2 >= 59.4054) || (c2 > 59.4051 && c2 < 59.4054 && 
     1102.5 + 
       6.32922*10^-31 Sqrt[
        3.27567*10^66 - 1.09189*10^65 c2 + 9.09908*10^62 c2^2] < 
      18.75 c2 + c3))) || ((
  1.61503*10^37 + 2.82069*10^33 c2^2 + 
   c2 (-4.2916*10^35 - 3.99645*10^33 c3) + 2.90144*10^35 c3 + 
   1.14149*10^33 c3^2)/(-2.01879*10^33 + 6.72929*10^31 c2 + 
   8.97238*10^31 c3) < c4 < 5.1917 c2 + 4.4417 c3 && 
 0 < c3 < -201.297 + 3.20418 c2 + 
   2.21826*10^-32 Sqrt[
    3.81708*10^67 - 1.47633*10^66 c2 + 1.41047*10^64 c2^2] && 
 59.4038 < c2 <= 59.4051)),
```

which is in terms of three variables c2 to c4, and plot the region in c2-c3-c4 space that is bounded by these inequalities?
I have tried using

```
region = Reduce[ (* Inequalities here*) , {c2, c3, c4}]
RegionPlot3D[region, {c2, -100, 100}, {c3, -100, 100}, {c4, -100, 100}]
```

but the resulting plot appears blank no matter what I do. Do I have to construct a function of some sort from this? Other examples seemed a little unclear to me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `FindInstance[inqualities, {c2, c3, c4}]` and then restrict the RegionPlot3D region to a neighborhood of the returned value.

Comment: @Carl Wolf : Your suggestion does not work for me. I obtain a sample {{c2 -> 59.4054, c3 -> 0.00632201, c4 -> 308.415}, {c2 -> 59.4047,   c3 -> 0.000921602, c4 -> 308.411}, {c2 -> 59.4094, c3 -> 0.00101499,   c4 -> 308.391}, {c2 -> 59.4073, c3 -> 0.00854468, 
  c4 -> 308.46}, {c2 -> 59.4054, c3 -> -0.017957, c4 -> 308.285}} of the size 5. Then RegionPlot3D[ineq, {c2, 59, 60}, {c3, -1, 1}, {c4, 308, 308.5}] performs an empty plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, one idea is to use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance) to get a possible `{c2, c3, c4}` value, and then to use [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D) in a neighborhood of this point. Depending on how large a neighborhood you use, you may need to increase the default [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints) option.

Another idea is to find out what the min and max values of `c2`, `c3`, and `c4` can be using [`MaxValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue)/[`MinValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinValue). For instance:

```
Quiet @ (
    c2min = MinValue[{c2,ineq}, {c2,c3,c4}, Reals];
    c2max = MaxValue[{c2,ineq}, {c2,c3,c4}, Reals];
    c3min = MinValue[{c3,ineq}, {c2,c3,c4}, Reals];
    c3max = MaxValue[{c3,ineq}, {c2,c3,c4}, Reals];
    c4min = MinValue[{c4,ineq}, {c2,c3,c4}, Reals];
    c4max = MaxValue[{c4,ineq}, {c2,c3,c4}, Reals];
);
```

Then, use [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D) over this neighborhood:

```
    RegionPlot3D[
        ineq,
        {c2, c2min, c2max},
        {c3, c3min, c3max},
        {c4, c4min, c4max},
        PlotPoints -> 100
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: This works - I guess the range of values is rather awkward to handle. I have another set of inequalities with a similar issue, with an even more asymmetric set of ranges. Do you suppose that the number of PlotPoints is the issue?